# PHP login script always returns "login failed"

Tags: php, postgresql, authentication, pdo

I have to give users the ability to log in for an assignment. At first, it seemed to me this script was simple enough to work, but everytime I try to log in with an existing account it gives me the "login failed" message. I don't know where my mistake lies. It's a PostgreSQL database, I'll enclose an image of it below.

```
<?php

require 'databaseaccess.php';
try {
$conn = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
phpinfo();
die();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$tablename = "users";

// sql-injection counter
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE userid = :username and userpass = :password");
$qry->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);
$qry->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);
$qry->execute();
$result = pg_query($qry);
$count = pg_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if ($count == 1) {

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("location:logingelukt.php");
} elseif ($count = -1) {
    echo "there has been an error";
} else{
    print $count;
    echo "login failed";
}
?>
```

I have no problems connecting to the database, so that's not an issue, it's just that it always sees `$count` as something else than zero. Another oddity is that the `print $count` command doesn't output anything.I use the account I made with postgresql outside of the page, which is just `admin:admin`. Also, I'm sure the right  variables are getting passed from the form.

EDIT: After using var_dump($result), as advised by kingalligator, it seems that $result is indeed NULL, thus empty. I'm gonna try using fetch() instead of pg_query().

Comment: Note that `elseif ($count = -1)` is an assignment. Is this intended as a comparison? Also, `stripslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string` are not needed since they are parameterized.

Comment: Whoops thanks small slip there. It doesn't change anything though. I also already tried commenting out the sql protections and that also didn't work.

Comment: @Caramiriel post it as the answer you have pointed the major mistake

Comment: @dianuj: It's not the major mistake, therefor it's not the real answer. I suspect mixing PDO and PG_* is the issue here, but I don't have enough PHP experience to confirm. I think using `count()` in the query and using `$qry->fetch()` would be the option to use here.

Comment: If your using PDO bind for your queries you don't need to use mysql_real_escape_string. PDO will do a better job at protecting you then you can do for yourself. I know this won't solve your problem, just nice to know imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're mixing PDO and pg_ functions.

Replace:

```
$result = pg_query($qry);
$count = pg_num_rows($result);
```

With:

```
$result = $qry->fetchAll();
$count  = count($result);
```

PDO Function reference can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Comment: `rowCount()` doesn't seem the case here. It represents the rows affected in an insert/delete/update query.

Comment: @Caramiriel ... oops ... I knew that ... fixed

Comment: Also, count shows the number of items in the array (represents columns of one row). I think `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` with `count()` is needed here. Able to confirm?

Comment: `fetchAll()` will return all rows as an array of arrays, not a single row ... `count()` will give the correct count ...

Comment: Gonna try that now, I didn't know you couldn't mix them.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that was the mistake. Never gonna forget that now!

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that you're actually getting data returned from your query? Try this:

```
var_dump($result);
```

To ensure that data is being returned from your query. You can still have a successful connection to a database, yet have a query that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should check your column userid at WHERE clause. I don't know the table columns, but is strange that 'userid' has the name of the user in:

```
"SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE userid = :username and userpass = :password"
```

Maybe it is causing the problem.

Comment: No I made it like that, in retrospect it should be username so I'm probably gonna change the column name but that's not the problem either.